# Setting a textfield value to empty after transitioning to a route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

After I transition to a route I would like to set the textfield value to empty.

I tried this in the controller but it isn't working:

```
  init: function() {
     this.set("filterterm", "");
  }
```

Here is a jsbin of my example: http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/111/edit

If I type "5" in the text box and click submit then the results change, but when I click All again, I would like to clear out the textfield.

Comment: Kindly check this [bin](http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/116/edit)

Comment: @seenivasan that removes the value in the text field when I press submit. I don't want that. I only want the value removed when I click some other link (i.e. mostsold, all, most rated etc. )

Comment: I failed to notice your subtle requirements.Check this [bin](http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/120/edit)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by putting this `this.set("filterterm", "");` after transitioning to your route:

```
submit: function (context) {
  var term = this.get("filterterm");
  var type = this.get("filtertype");

  console.log(type);
  console.log(term);

  var obj = {};
  obj[type] = term;

  this.transitionToRoute("posts.dynamicfinder", App.Response.find(obj));
  this.set("filterterm", "");
}
```

or you can place it in your route:

```
App.PostsDynamicfinderRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model) {
    console.log(model);
    return { 'some_id': 'whateveryouwant' };
  },

  enter: function() {
    this.controllerFor('posts').set('filterterm', '');
  }
});
```

Comment: `enter` is private `willTransition` is better suited and public API

Comment: This works but my only problem is that it clears the text field soon as I hit "submit". What I want, rather, is that the textfield should only clear when other links are clicked (i.e. all, mostsold, mostrated). etc. Basically any other link than submit